# Angular-Tree-Grid ( Custom CSS Styling on Header and Rows )

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am using Angular-Tree-Grid and want to style the Grid/Table like change Header font style . Put background color on rows etc. How can I do it ?

```
 
    TreeGridComponent.html
    <div class="container">
            <db-angular-tree-grid
            #angularGrid [data]="data" 
            [configs]="configs"
            >
            </db-angular-tree-grid>
        </div>
```

---

```
TreeGridComponent.ts
```

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularTreeGridComponent } from 'angular-tree-grid';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tree-grid',
      templateUrl: './tree-grid.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tree-grid.component.css']
    })
    
    export class TreeGridComponent {
      @ViewChild('angularGrid') angularGrid!: AngularTreeGridComponent;
      data: any = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Gross Sales',
          age: 60,
          weight: 60,
          gender: 1,
          parent: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Gross Units',
          age: 40,
          weight: 95,
          gender: 1,
          parent: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Gross Sales Dollars',
          age: 36,
          weight: 105,
          gender: 1,
          parent: 0,
        },
        
      ];
       // Define the columns for the tree grid
        configs:any = {
          id_field: 'id',
          parent_id_field: 'parent',
          parent_display_field: 'name',
          columns: [
            {
              name: 'name',
              header: 'Name',
              width: '100px',
            },
            {
              name: 'age',
              header: 'July 2020',
            },
            {
              name: 'weight',
              header: 'July 2020',
            },
            {
              name: 'gender',
              header: 'September 2020',
            },
            
            
          ],
        };
    }
```

I tried using the following link : https://github.com/debabratapatra/angular-tree-grid . But couldn;t find anything to cater my need. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: It's literally on the documentation you linked. https://github.com/debabratapatra/angular-tree-grid#css `header_class` or something more customized `header_renderer`.

Comment: Doesn't work . Can you help with how to use it ? Thanks for answering @penleychan